# CSS animate transition of background image getting darker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

So I'm building a page that has a background image:

```
body {
    background:url(images/bg.png) center center no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover
}
```

The page loads with a div that looks like a alert/message. When this div loads I want a short animation of the background-image getting darker,
Right now I use this:

```
back { 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%
}
```

This makes it darker, but I want this to happen gradually in a smooth transition/animation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) for this. I don't know what your HTML looks like, but here's a little demo:

```css
.back { 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:500px;
}

@keyframes back-change {
   from { background: rgba(133,133,133,.95) }
     to { background: rgba(0,0,0,.95) }
}

.back {
  animation: back-change 4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```

I set it to change from light to dark over 4s in a linear pattern. You can change the duration or change the pattern to whatever you want (none, infinite, etc.).

Notice that the name `back-change` that follows the `@keyframes` word is what you'll have to call in the the `animation` property later on. If you change the name in one spot, you'll have to change it in both.

Here's a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/55wg49oL/) as well for messing around with on your own.

---

You can also use [CSS3 Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) as well. These have been supported a little longer in web browsers.

```css
.back { 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:500px;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.back:hover {
    background-color: rgba(133,133,133,.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```

Again, here's a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/Lv7n5o9f/) for you to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple css [transition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) and jQuery `addClass()` method only to set element class attribute.

JS

```
$( window ).load( function() {
    $( '.overlay' ).addClass( 'dark' );
});
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.dark{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsy9cpvk/)

Comment: Thanks, this was simple to integrate

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a transition, not an animation:

In this example I'll change the opacity to fade out when you hover over it...

```
.TransitStyle {

 background:rgba(0,0,0,.95);
 display:block;
 height:100%;
 left:0;
 opacity:1;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%

-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-moz-transition-property: opacity;
-ms-transition-property: opacity;
-o-transition-property: opacity;
 transition-property: opacity;

-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
-ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
-o-transition-timing-function: linear;
 transition-timing-function: linear;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.TransitStyle:hover {
 opacity: 0.0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'd like for this to happen on page load with no previous event like hover

Comment: CSS3 transitions have been supported without prefixes for three and two years in Firefox and Chrome, respectively (IE didn't support them until IE10, but it never used prefixes; there's no such thing as `-ms-transition-property`, for example). Opera has supported it sans-prefix for even longer. The only use for prefixes here is for `-webkit-` for people using an old version of Safari.